# Unbinding in module

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am creating a shiny module that inputs a dataset, and outputs a DataTable with the data and a numeric input. I know that with inputs in DataTables you need to bind and unbind the elements with javascript each time the table is redrawn or else you will only be able to read the values from the initial table. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/ZUMBGGl1sss) I don't know if the issue is with namespaces, but I can't seem to get the elements of the table to succesfully unbind inside a module. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
# module UI
dtInputUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tbl <- DT::dataTableOutput(ns("tbl"))
  btn <- actionButton(ns("btn"),"Submit")
  scrpt1 <- tags$script(HTML(
    "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('display', function(html) {
      var w=window.open();
      $(w.document.body).html(html);})"
    ))
  # doesn't appear to work properly
  scrpt2 <- tags$script(HTML(paste0(
    "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbind-DT', function(id) {
      Shiny.unbindAll($('#'+id).find('table').DataTable().table().node());
    })")))
  tagList(
    btn,tbl,scrpt1,scrpt2
    )
}
# module server
dtInput <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  ns <- session$ns
  # numeric inputs
  form <- reactive({
    n <- nrow(data())
    inputs <- character(n)
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(numericInput(
        ns(paste0("Form",i)),value=0,label=NULL)
        )
    }
    session$sendCustomMessage('unbind-DT',ns("tbl"))
    data.frame(data(), RATE=inputs)
  })
  # datatable
  output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(form(),
                server=FALSE,escape=FALSE,selection='none',
                rownames=FALSE,options=list(
                  paging=FALSE,
                  bInfo=0,
                  bSort=0,
                  bfilter=0,
                    preDrawCallback=DT::JS(
                      'function() {Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
                   drawCallback=DT::JS(
                     'function(settings) {Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')
                ))

  vals <- reactive({
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(data())),function(i) {
      value <- ifelse(is.null(input[[paste0("Form",i)]]),NA,input[[paste0("Form",i)]])
    }))
  })
  # generate webpage when button clicked
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    HTML <- paste0("<p>",paste0(vals(),collapse=" </p> <p>"),"</p>")
    session$sendCustomMessage("display",HTML)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    selectInput("choose","Choose data",choices=c("mtcars","iris")),
    dtInputUI("example")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactive({
    req(input$choose)
    get(input$choose)
  })

  callModule(dtInput,"example",reactive(dat()))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Enter anything in the inputs and press the button and a webpage with the inputs is created. Change the dataset, enter different info in the inputs, and press the button again and you get the same info as before, which tells me that the old inputs didn't successfully unbind.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In `dtinputUI` you forgot to include `scrpt2` in your `tagList`. That is all.

Comment: That was a typo from when I copied my code. Not the cause of my error. Good eye though

Comment: Maybe I don't get your problem then. On my computer, if I enter 1 in row 1 and submit, I get the extra window with 1 0 0 ... 0. If I change the dataset, enter 2 in the first row and submit, I get 2 0 0 ... 0 and so on. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: You're right. Maybe I did have the typo. Thanks